# What exactly does the word "term" represent here?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I recently started reading research papers in English. There have been some hiccups, but I was always able to understand the meaning from context, but now I'm stuck.

> Exactly what is an "idea"? In our work we take a simplistic definition: idea = **term**. Parsing the document for **terms** is easily done, in our case, using the Brill tagger.

This is part of paper on automatic text summarization ([*Text Summarization via Hidden Markov Models and Pivoted QR Matrix Decomposition*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.23.6778), Conroy and O'Leary 2001). It's an algorithm that takes text and extracts sentences that summarize the text. They mention the Brill tagger, which is a method that tags text for part-of-speech (it can analyze sentence and mark words for their part-of-speech).

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The cited text tells you that *for their current purposes*, the authors are going to equate ***idea*** and ***term***. That's to say - any word that represents an "idea" can be classified as a "term" (I assume prepositions, pronouns, etc. don't meaningfully represent *ideas*). This doesn't really seem to be about *learning English* - it's about software-based approaches to AI.

Comment: Since this is a technical question rather than a beginners' English question, I'm suggesting a migration to [linguistics.se], to be filed under [\[computational-linguistics\]](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-linguistics). ([cs.se] or [cstheory.se] might also work.)

Comment: As others have indicated, *term* is a technical term ;-) (word) in computer science, logic, and other language theories, and its precise meaning depends on the context. An *idea* is a mental notion, and is typically not defined precisely and constructively. The paper apparently wants to say that they are trying to model ideas using terms. (That's a guess. I'm also guessing that the paper is not very clear and perhaps not very solid theoretically. ;-))

Comment: Mentioning Brill tagger is likely that they are talking about [POS tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging). Just like other comments state, the word *term* in this context is a technical one. Usually, in [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) tasks in [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), the term *term* usually refers to "terminal node" in [syntax trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_tree) in context.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is there in the quotation:

> a simplistic definition: idea = term.

Idea is a little word that can represent something huge and complex, term strips it down to basics - an idea could easily consist of many terms.

From the OED (definition 13b in the current online edition):

> Any word or group of words expressing a notion or conception, or denoting an object of thought; an expression (for something)

I'm pretty sure that that is what the authors are talking about here - they are parsing the documents for these conceptual building blocks.